# CakePHP 3.x update records with jQueryUI Sortable

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, jquery-ui-sortable

In one of the views I have implemented a list that can be reordered by drag and drop with `jQueryUI Sortable`.

The output of the list in `meetings.ctp` looks like following:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <?php foreach($meetings as $meeting): ?>
    <li class="ui-state-default">>
      <?php echo  $meeting['name'] . ' ' . $meeting[place]; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The list of meetings is provided based on priority:

```
$upcommingMeetings_query = $this->MeetingsTasks->find('all')
    ->order(['Meetings.priority' => 'ASC']);
```

What I need to get done is to update the priority of a `Meeting` record once it it has been moved. However, I can only find example for how to do this in older versions of CakePHP using `JsHelper` which is no longer available.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated. If there is any code that I should have shared, please ask for it.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove extra `>` from line `<li class="ui-state-default">>` and then use the `stop` event of `sortable`

```
$( "#selector" ).sortable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    //Invoke the serialize method:
    var sorted = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    console.log(sorted);
    //output: 'sort[]=4&sort[]=1&sort[]=2&sort[]=5&sort[]=3'
    //here goes your ajax request to server
    $.ajax({
       url: 'someURL',
       cache: false,
       type: 'post',
       data: sorted,
       success: function(result) {//parse it here}
    });
  }
});
```

Your `.ctp` code should be something like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <?php foreach($meetings as $meeting): ?>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="sort-<?php echo $meeting['id']; ?>">
           <?php echo  $meeting['name'] . ' ' . $meeting['place']; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

You can customize `<li class="ui-state-default" id="sort-<?php echo $meeting['id']; ?>">` this part by replacing `sort` with anyhing you want.

On controller part you will have to parse it in `foreach` loop and update your `db` accordingly, or you may save as it is. [working link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adqdjg)